# Fragment can not be cloned after appended?

Tags: javascript

The following code snipset is simplified from listing 12.4 of "Secrets of Javascript Ninja" to inject a new element to multiple existed ones.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="test1">Test 1</div>
        <div id="test2">Test 2</div>
        <div id="test3">Test 3</div>

        <script>
            const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
            const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            const div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = "<b>Element Injected</b>";
            fragment.appendChild(div.firstChild);
            for (let i = 0; divs[i]; i++) {
                divs[i].appendChild(i > 0 ? fragment.cloneNode(true) : fragment);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that the line:

```
divs[i].appendChild(i > 0 ? fragment.cloneNode(true) : fragment);
```

does not work correctly because only the "test1" element is injected.
So I changed it to:

```
divs[i].appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
```

This injects new element to all elements (test1, test2 and test3).
How to use fragment for the first element (test1) and fragment.cloneNode(true) for the rest (test2, test3) as the author intended?

Answer (score 1):

When you append fragment to somewhere, all its content gets passed to that place and fragment becomes empty. If you want to add its content multiple times, you have to clone it each time.

Here's an example that shows the behavior:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<b>Element Injected</b>";
fragment.appendChild(div.firstChild);

console.log(`fragment before appending has ${fragment.childNodes.length} children`);
divs[0].appendChild(fragment);
console.log(`fragment after appending has ${fragment.childNodes.length} children`);
```

```html
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Test 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As marzelin said fragment become blank when you append somewhere, you can do in this way same process.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<b>Element Injected</b>";
fragment.appendChild(div.firstChild);
var t1 = fragment.cloneNode(true);
for (let i = 0; divs[i]; i++) {
    t2 = t1;
    divs[i].appendChild(i > 0 ? t2.cloneNode(true) : fragment);
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
        <div id="test2">Test 2</div>
        <div id="test3">Test 3</div>
```